# Is it safe to install Bitcoin Core using a package manager?

Tags: security, installation, bitcoin-qt-setup

For example, on macOS:

```bash
brew install --cask bitcoin-core
```

Or on Ubuntu:

```bash
snap install bitcoin-core
```

Etc.

In particular, what attack vectors might I be exposing myself to if I choose to install Bitcoin Core using a package manager?

Using Homebrew as an example:

1. I presume that [download hashes are checked](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/efe28792b2f57bc57e364fc5afd9b875b1127e37/Casks/b/bitcoin-core.rb) in Homebrew?
2. Are hash signatures checked?
3. Does Homebrew have a mechanism that ensures that only a Bitcoin Core maintainer can update a package on Homebrew?
4. Could I still be vulnerable to a malicious/compromised Homebrew maintainer who changes the download URL and hash?
5. Are there any other similar issues or risks?

(N.B.: If the only "safe" method is to build from source or to download Bitcoin Core directly, it's fine to note this and why, but I ask that you please keep answers focused on any risks associated with using a package manager instead.)

Thanks!

Comment: Homebrew checks download hashes to ensure the integrity of downloaded files. It does not natively support cryptographic signature verification for packages. There is a potential risk of a malicious or compromised Homebrew maintainer changing the download URL and hash for a package.

Comment: Thank you, @ManiT! It sounds like a more niche package manager is needed (and may eventually develop) that maintains an appropriate chain of verifiable trust for higher risk packages like various Bitcoin and LN implementations, etc, though I am likely underappreciating the complexities in this idea.